# :nth-child() target every third item

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to target every 1st, 2nd and 3rd `.pricing-example` on a page, in order to apply a different background colour to each. However, using the code below, when 3 `.pricing-example` elements are on a page, `nth-child(1n)` targets item 1 & 3, and `nth-child(3n)` targets item 2, which I don't understand. What I am trying to achieve is to enable a different background colour on every third item, so as follows:

- Item 1 = Background 1
- Item 2 = Background 2
- Item 3 = Background 3
- Item 4 = Background 1
- Item 5 = Background 2
- Item 6 = Background 3
- Item 7 = Background 1
- and so on....

**HTML**

```
<div class="blocks">
    <figure class="custom-block image"></figure>
    <figure class="custom-block text"></figure>
    <figure class="custom-block pricing-example"></figure>
    <figure class="custom-block pricing-example"></figure>
    <figure class="custom-block pricing-example"></figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pricing-example {

    // Alternate background colours of images when multiple blocks
    &:nth-child(1n) {
        background-color: red;
    }
    &:nth-child(2n) {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    &:nth-child(3n) {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question how to do this in CSS or in Sass? If the latter, please specify that. If the former, please provide the CSS rather than the Sass code that you have.

Comment: this is still not enough. you are using `&` in the SASS code but we don't see the upper selector to know `&` refer to what. Try to consider a full code

Comment: Updated question @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 4):

The pseudo-class formula is (An+B). Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

> Represents elements whose numeric position in a series of siblings
>   matches the pattern An+B, for every positive integer or zero value of
>   n. The index of the first element is 1. The values A and B must both
>   be integers.

So you want to use `3n+1`, `3n+2`, and `3n+3`:

```css
p:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: red;
}

p:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: blue;
}

p:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: technically his code is also correct: https://jsfiddle.net/mqbaxtgj/. I guess the issue is with his HTML structure

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well while his code should *work*, it's not really the right way to address the elements as he's constantly overwriting previous elements. But you're probably right that there's a problem with the OP's HTML.

Comment: Hi both, have updated the question with the HTML. It sits on a page amongst other items, but as I understand it the code should still target every third item?

Comment: @dungey_140 *It sits on a page amongst other items,* show us the html with the other items

Comment: I have updated the question to show more HTML. I would like to target figure.pricing-example as per the question (every first, second, third).

Comment: @dungey_140 you should update the original question with your requirements in your comment and also update the CSS to be a bit more specific to what you are trying to target. You added HTML, but the CSS has no relation to that without context.

Comment: Updated question @disinfor

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```css
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li>Item four</li>
  <li>Item five</li>
  <li>Item six</li>
  <li>Item seven</li>
  <li>Item eight</li>
  <li>Item nine</li>
  <ul>
```

SCSS version:

```
ul {
    li {
        &:nth-child(3n+1) {
            background-color: red;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n+2) {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n+3) {
           background-color: green;
        }
     }
 }
```

Here's a really great tool to test your `nth` selectors: https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: what he's doing is also correct: https://jsfiddle.net/mqbaxtgj/ I suspect there is an issue with the HTML code we don't have

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, you're on to something - there's some information definitely missing.